# How to remove App Ids from iPhone Provisioning Portal

Tags: iphone, app-store, provisioning

While experimenting with iPhone app development, we have **several AppIDs which should be deleted** - except I can't find any way to delete them! What can I do with them?

If delete is not available, how about renaming, hiding or permanently disabling?

**UPDATE:**

Beginning April 2013 Apple allows deleting AppIDs. Whoaa!

Comment: Apparently you can delete now, a welcome change.

Answer (score 195, accepted):

- Delete: No
- Rename: No
- Hide: No
- Disable: No

If you create an App ID, be prepared to live with it for the rest of your life; App IDs are the herpes of iPhone provisioning.

Comment: and what about the genius who made the fixed length table showing them, so that you can only see the first, unimportant, part of their name? quite cool eh? :/

Comment: @hariseldon78 Hover over those truncated names and you get the full name showing as a "tooltip" - assuming you're using an OS that can hover, e.g. not... erm... iOS! :-) Still stinky UI design but hopefully it eases your pain a fraction.

Comment: @b-ryce The portal is totally awesome, I deeply enjoy having to create/re-create new CSR's multiple times when additional app. entitlements don't appear against provisioning profiles... it's not like I was planning to use that extra hour or two of my life.

Comment: Nah. Not completely. Still remains for active apps. I really can't figure out any sane reason to stick to a *name* instead of numeric PK value in their own database. This shows how Apple is really suck in designing service stuffs...

Answer (score 1):

The delete button is **reappeared** again on **Apple Developers**

Now you can delete your App ID again by following these 2 steps:

1. Click your AppID and you will see a view like this:
   [image]
2. Click **Edit** on the bottom of the view

[image]

3. There you see **Delete** button

Hope it helps